# How useful will JDBC be in an event-driven program?

Tags: scala, events, asynchronous, jdbc

I'm writing an event-driven architecture in Scala and I need to manage a database using it.

I was wondering if using JDBC, which only supports synchronous calls, would be a good solution to my problem?

I'd thought of writing an asynchronous wrapper for the calls to JDBC, but will it really  tackle my concerns of the thread being blocked because of the database call?

Answer (score 3):

This is really good question, and actually there's no single good answer to it.

It really depends on your database, its protocol and driver implementation. First of all, some databases, e.g. Cassandra, have asynchronous capabilities built into the protocol level. Should make it easier to work in the event-driven model, right? Not exactly - if you get gigabytes of data over slow connection you *may* block on the network level.

Other databases have only synchronous protocol and thus can block your resources, right? Not exactly - there are connection pools that prevent some of the issues with blocking.

So, depending on your application architecture and data you're accessing, you may need to isolate a layer of data access, that will wrap the JDBC connections and provide asynchronous capabilities. This layer would scale up and down depending on availability of open connections (e.g. actors holding the connection, and supervisor that will spawn new DB connection actors if there are no free databases, and create new threads using `PinnedDispatcher`).

In other cases, with specific drivers, you may stick with just JDBC wrapped into Future an hope that driver does it magic for you.

If you build large-scale application, you may want to even separate persistence access logic completely into, say, RabbitMQ, and use RPC for accessing the database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know JDBC drivers are synchronous. Maybe you can design your system so your "main" actors asynchronously dispatch requests to  background "JDBC" actors that deal with the JDBC driver?

Answer (score -1):

I also try to implement fully asnyc architecture and DB calls are my bottleneck. I found that good idea is to use connection polled JDBC C3P0 driver. Here is usage example in Scala Slick framework [link](http://fernandezpablo85.github.io/2013/04/07/slick_connection_pooling.html). Connection pooling is one of the solutions in which you have ready to use connections to your DB. It's better than spawning new connection for each request and after complition removing that connection. Here is full website od C3P0 project [link](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)